# SQL 2005 Replicated Database Indexes

Tags: sql-server-2005, replication

I have setup a SQL 2005 database replication (transactional) between two servers. I have noticed today that the non-clustered indexes do not seem to have gone across to the replicated database.

I have had a look round sql management studio and cant find anything to create a script for them on mass (there are 100's of tables), and i also cant see anything in the replication options to send them across.

Is there an easy way to copy them across, or include them in the initial snapshot at least as a last case i can re-create the snapshot?

Cheers
Luke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to script the indexes and run it in the replicated database. The script that I use to do that, you can find it here

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic401795-566-2.aspx